# required WHERE AND clause in addition to multiple OR's

Tags: mysql

I need to return all items from 't' (thread) that include 'menu_item_id' = 1.

In addition, I need to filter all the above results based on f.tag.

```
SELECT t.*, u.username AS owner, uu.username AS replyname, a.location
FROM thread t
INNER JOIN filter_thread as ft ON t.thread_id = ft.thread_id
INNER JOIN filter as f ON f.filter_id = ft.filter_id
INNER JOIN users u ON t.owner_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN users uu ON t.last_post_id = uu.id
INNER JOIN user_profiles AS up ON u.id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN avatars AS a ON up.avatar_id = a.id
WHERE t.menu_item_id='1'
AND f.tag LIKE '%hello%'
OR f.tag LIKE '%world%'
```

problem area: `AND f.tag LIKE '%hello%'
    OR f.tag LIKE '%world%'`

The important thing to realize is that 'hello' and 'world' might not always be in the query.  In addition, there might be 3 more searches tacked onto it, however, the `menu_item_id` will always be searched for.

I don't want all the results to require each of the f.tags, i just want to the results to contain any of them (OR).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis to specify the precedence of the `AND` and `OR`.

```
a AND (b OR c)
```

vs.

```
(a AND b) OR c
```

For example:

```
WHERE t.menu_item_id='1'
  AND (    f.tag LIKE '%hello%'
        OR f.tag LIKE '%world%'
      )
```

This will return only rows that have menu_item_id = '1' AND which have tag containing either 'hello' or 'world'.

Comment: Thanks. Never used parenthesis in mysql, didn't even think about it!

Answer (score 3):

Like... parentheses?

```
SELECT t.*, u.username AS owner, uu.username AS replyname, a.location
FROM thread t
INNER JOIN filter_thread as ft ON t.thread_id = ft.thread_id
INNER JOIN filter as f ON f.filter_id = ft.filter_id
INNER JOIN users u ON t.owner_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN users uu ON t.last_post_id = uu.id
INNER JOIN user_profiles AS up ON u.id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN avatars AS a ON up.avatar_id = a.id
WHERE t.menu_item_id='1'
AND (
    f.tag LIKE '%hello%'
 OR f.tag LIKE '%world%'
)
```

If the problem is that this query is made dynamically, just add a `1` to the front.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if this answers your question, but I like to use parenthesis to make things easier to read, like so

```
SELECT t.*, u.username AS owner, uu.username AS replyname, a.location
FROM thread t
INNER JOIN filter_thread as ft ON t.thread_id = ft.thread_id
INNER JOIN filter as f ON f.filter_id = ft.filter_id
INNER JOIN users u ON t.owner_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN users uu ON t.last_post_id = uu.id
INNER JOIN user_profiles AS up ON u.id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN avatars AS a ON up.avatar_id = a.id
WHERE t.menu_item_id='1'
AND (f.tag LIKE '%hello%'
OR f.tag LIKE '%world%')
```

Now it is saying where t.menu_item_id = 1 AND either of the conditionals in the parenthesis are true, rather than saying (t.menu_item_id = 1 AND f.tag LIKE '%hello%') OR f.tag LIKE '%world%'

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use parentheses?

```
WHERE t.menu_item_id='1' AND (f.tag LIKE '%hello%' OR f.tag LIKE '%world%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code generated dynamically through PHP:

```
    $sql_select = "SELECT t.*, u.username AS owner, uu.username AS replyname, a.location";
    $sql_from = " FROM ";
    $sql_where = " WHERE ";
    $sql_joins = "";
    $sql_order = " ORDER BY t.replystamp DESC
                    LIMIT $threadstart, $limit";  
    $sql_from .= ' thread t ';
    $sql_where .= " t.menu_item_id=$menu_item_id";
    $sql_joins .= ' INNER JOIN filter_thread as ft ON t.thread_id = ft.thread_id
                    INNER JOIN filter as f ON f.filter_id = ft.filter_id
                    INNER JOIN users u ON t.owner_id = u.id 
                    INNER JOIN users uu ON t.last_post_id = uu.id
                    INNER JOIN user_profiles AS up ON u.id = up.user_id
                    INNER JOIN avatars AS a ON up.avatar_id = a.id';
    if ($ac_total > 0) {
        $sql_where .= " AND (";
        for ($i=0; $i < $ac_total; $i++)
        {
            if ($i == 0)
            {
                $sql_where .= "f.tag LIKE '%$active_category[$i]%'";
            } else {
                " OR f.tag LIKE '%$active_category[$i]%')";
            }
        }
        $sql_where .= ")";
    }
    $sql = $sql_select . $sql_from . $sql_joins . $sql_where . $sql_order;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Thanks for the help!